# using sed to replace ^[(s3B with blank space

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I'm trying to use sed with perl to replace ^[(s3B with an empty string in several files.

s/^[(s3B// isn't working though, so I'm wondering what else I could try.

Comment: You probably need to escape the parenthesis.  Add a \ in front of them and try it.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information. Why are you using both sed and Perl? Can you do this in just Perl? What have you tried? What is the result of what you tried? It'll help us understand your issues better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are several characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions. `^` is a start-of-line anchor, `[` opens a character class, and `(` opens a capture.

You can escape all non-alphanumerics in a Perl string by preceding it with `\Q`, so you can safely use

```
s/\Q^[(s3B//
```

which is equivalent to, and more readable than

```
s/\^\[\(s3B//
```

Comment: For completeness, you may end the quoting with `\E`

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the special characters:

```
 $ echo "^[(s3B AAA ^[(s3B"|sed 's/\^\[[(]s3B//g'
  AAA 

 $ echo "^[(s3B AAA ^[(s3B" >file.txt
 $ perl -p -i -e 's/\^\[[(]s3B//g' file.txt      
 $ cat file.txt 
  AAA
```

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work, 

if I have a string like ^[(s3BThis is a line

and I want to get rid of the characters, can I just use the command:

s/\^\[[(]s3B//g

Comment: I think the difference is that there aren't any spaces separating the words in my files

Comment: You need to quote following three characters: ^ [ (

Comment: In your comment you didn't quote "[" (left square bracket). Also, notice there are two ways of quoting a special character: by prepending backslash and by putting the character into square brackets (unquoted).

Comment: `s/\^\[[(]s3B//g` is just confusing.

Comment: @Borodin Why did it confuse you?

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with ANSI sequences (xterm color sequences, escape sequences), then ^[ is not '^' followed by '[' but rather an unprintable character ESC, ASCII code 0x1B.

To put that character into a sed expression you need to use \x1B in GNU sed, or see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable/  . You can also insert special characters directly into your command line using ctrl+v in Bash line editing.

Answer (score 0):

In regex "^", "[" and "(" (and many others) are special characters used for special regex features, if you are referencing the characters themselves you should preceed them with "\". 
The correct substitution reges would be:

```
$string =~ s/\^\[\(3B//g
```

if you want to replace all occurences.

Comment: Even better: Use `\Q` and `\E` _quoting characters to turn off regular expression magic: $string =~ s/\Q^[(s3B\E//;`. I also suspect that `^[` isn't just a two character string, but is an escape character.